# Populating a dictionary from text file

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

I'm trying to populate a dictionary from a text file which has two columns author and title divided by a comma. My code is below

```
f = open('books.txt', 'r')          
books = {}
for l in f:
    author,title = l.strip().split()
    if author in books:
        books[author].append(title)
    else:
        books[author]=[title]
f.close()
```

I get the error "too many variables to unpack" at line 1. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about your line numeration, but the offending line should be `author, title = l.strip().split()`, since "Too many variables to unpack" is raised when the number of variables in both sides of an assignement is not equal.

Comment: That is correct, and that error is caused by splitting on an empty string.

Comment: wait, how is it possible you got the error at line 1? you mean the traceback leads you to `f = open('books.txt', 'r')`??

Comment: apologies, the error WAS at line 4, and it was the missing comma in .split(). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Switch to using JSON in your file and then just load the dictionary using json library books = json.load(file_desc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things, you should probably use the `with open` way of reading a file in python (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)). It automatically closes at the end of the block.

Secondly, you split on an empty string. It should be `.split(',')` to split on a comma.

Finally, I would consider using the [csv class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the csv file. This is especially useful if there are commas in the book titles or authors.

Working example of *your* code:

```
with open('books.txt', 'r') as book_file:
    books = {}
    for l in book_file:  
        author,title = l.strip().split(',')
        if author in books:
            books[author].append(title)
        else:
            books[author]=[title]

print books
```